# Connecting to root domain - AWS Route 53 EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I set up an EC2 instance with an elastic IP. I registered a domain with Namecheap and transferred my name servers from them to Route 53.

I created an A-IP4 record and plugged in my elastic IP address. Didn't work.

Then I decided to try creating the A-IP4 using www. It worked.

I've tried setting up a pointer from www.mysite.com to mysite.com, no luck. I've searched around for hours in Amazon's docs but still can't figure out how to get it setup. Does anyone know how to set this up so I can access my root domain? I'd hate to be stuck with www.

Comment: Are you sure the webserver (Apache or IIS) listening for requests to the naked domain?

Comment: This is not a DNS problem, make sure your webserver is listening to both the naked and www domains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can not create an A record at the zone apex, only an AWS-specific Alias type.

The Alias can refer to an ELB, S3 website, CloudFront distribution or another Route 53 record set. You have a couple of options:

a) put your instance behind an ELB, and create example.com as an Alias record pointing to your ELB. Or,

b) Create example.com as an Alias which points to the www.example.com CNAME.

Comment: Thanks man, that's pretty much what I had been reading everywhere else. I was hoping there was another solution I was missing but I guess not.

Comment: @Mike Ryan, I am trying option b.  When creating Alias, what Type do I need to select?  I tried A and CNAME.  It does not seem to accept either to point to www CNAME.

Comment: @Nabarun - I did this with A records. Is the www record set a "normal" CNAME, i.e. not an Alias?

Comment: @Mike Ryan, www record is a CNAME pointing to another CNAME record.  Apex Zone Alias record does not allow to pick up this CNAME record.  It is not on the available alias list.

Comment: That suggests you can not use Alias -> CNAME -> CNAME.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and was a little confused. Turns out it's pretty easy. First create the www.example.com name pointing to your elastic ip as an A record. Then create an additional A record as an alias and leave the name section blank. That will allow your ec2 instance to resolve to zone apex (root) and www.